# A line in NodeJS logs correct data but the next line logs `undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function merge(sections, items) {
    console.log(items); // logs correct items
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(items); // logs undefined
        var items = _.groupBy(items,'section_id');
        // items = _.groupBy(items, 'section_id'); // the above items logs correct without the `var`
        resolve({resolved: true});
    })
}
```

This is super weird. Don't know why the items in the first `console.log` are printing fine. But, once inside the promise, it's printing `undefined`. There's no global variables with the same name.

What could cause this?

But it worked when I removed the var before the items inside promise. Why did it work?

Comment: `items` is a local variable inside your promise

Comment: "There's no global variables with the same name." — But there is the `items` scoped to the merge function and the other `items` scoped to the anonymous function passed as the first argument to `Promise`. That's two variables with the same name in nested scopes.

Comment: both the things working for me. Check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/awxons3h/). I think you are using that same variable some where else too.

Comment: But, isn't the `console.log` before the `var items = `. Still?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed — Irrelevant. `var` is hoisted. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Hoisting. That's it. Thanks